Display JavaScript Fetch for JsonResponse 2 Tables on HTML
I'm learning JavaScript right now and I'm trying to display data from 2 tables, which is profile and posts of the user profile.
Here is the API view
API
I tried to display the data on index.html using JavaScript.
index.js
function load_profile(author_id) {
    
    // Load posts list
    fetch(`/profile/${author_id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        // Print profile & posts
        console.log(response.prof);
        console.log(response.posts);

        const content_profile = document.createElement('div');
        content_profile.className = "content_profile";
        
        const user = document.createElement('p');
        user.innerHTML = `<h3>${response.prof.user}</h3>`;
    
        const followers = document.createElement('p');
        followers.innerHTML = `Follower: ${response.prof.followers}`;

        const following = document.createElement('p');
        following.innerHTML = `Following: ${response.prof.following}`;

        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.className = "btn btn-primary";
        a.innerHTML = "Follow";
   
        content_profile.append(user, followers, following, a);
        document.querySelector('#profile').append(content_profile);

        response.posts.forEach(post =>{
            const list_item = document.createElement('ul');
            const data_author = document.createElement('li');
            data_author.innerHTML = post.author+" at "+post.timestamp+" say:";
            const data_content = document.createElement('li');
            data_content.innerHTML = post.content;
            const data_like = document.createElement('li');
            data_like.innerHTML = post.like+" Likes";

            list_item.append(data_author, data_content, data_like);
            document.querySelector('#postbox').append(list_item);
        })
    })
}

index.html
{% extends "sinpage/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="userpage">
            <h2>{{ request.user.username }}</h2>
            <div id="postit">
                <form id="compose-form">
                    {{form.as_p}}
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="profile"></div>
        <div class="col" id="postbox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'sinpage/index.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

So the profile data show up but the posts data didn't. This is my first time displaying 2 data using JavaScript, I think I'm doing it wrong? Any pointer is appreciated. Thanks.
index.js updated. Now it's working! :)

What steps have you taken to debug this? Is the problem in the python or JS?

I assume that all information is in 'response'. Why the third .then statement? You could do everything in the second. If you don't want that, then do a 'return prof' in the second .then. That's probably why 'datas' is 'undefined'

Ooh, that's why it's not showing. I think get it now. Thx

Example
function load() {
    fetch('https://my/api/call')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // do something with data.profile
            return data
        })
        .then(data => {
            // do something with data.posts
        })
}


I have update my function, now the data show up. Thank you.
